# MarkLogic: write data to documents in query and then access those documents in the same query

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

In MarkLogic I want to write functions that create documents/ maps, then access those documents/ maps in that query - I believe doing this will avoid memory issues/ timing out.

But, unless I run each function in a separate query, the code doesn't work. How can I force one function to run only when another has completely finished: i.e, saved a document to disk?

**Edit:**
The problem I have is that I want to find the distinct values of two elements, say  and  in a collection of documents. I also want to know how often each combination of values for those elements occurs.

The result I want to be able to create would look like, in a collection of documents that each contain an element  holding an id and  containing a string representing a person:

```
<pairs>
    <pair frequency="5">
       <thing-1>01257</thing-1>
       <thing-2>John Smith</thing-2>
    </pair>
</pairs>
```

This is the code that I have been using:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace local = "http://www.local.com";

declare variable $collections := 'A' ;
declare variable $query-name := 'A-query' ;
declare variable $number-of-documents := count(collection($collections)) ; 
declare variable $map-collection := concat ($query-name, '-maps') ;

(: create a temporary collection to store data saved during the query :)
declare function local:document-set-creator($counter, $iteration) {
 if ($counter > ($number-of-documents + 1000)) 
  then ()
   else (
    let $name := concat($query-name, '-part', $iteration) 
         let $uris := for $i in subsequence(cts:uris( (), (), cts:collection-query($collections) ), $counter, 1000) return $i 
     let $results := 
                <results>
                    {
                        for $i in $uris
                            let $thing-1 := cts:search(/*/element/thing-1 , cts:document-query($i) )
                            let $thing-2 := cts:search(/*/element/thing-2 , cts:document-query($i) )
                          return
                                <pair>
                                 <thing1>{$thing-1/normalize-space(string())}</thing1>
                                 <thing2>{$thing-2/normalize-space(string())}</thing2>
                                </pair>
                            }
                    </results>   
            let $path-name := concat('pairs-', $name, '.xml') 

      return
        xdmp:document-insert($path-name , $results, (), $query-name )
         ,
        xdmp:sleep(1000)
          ,
        local:document-set-creator(($counter + 1000), ($iteration + 1))

    )
} ;

(: take values from the pairs list, concatenate them and put them into a map
  key = concatenated value
  value = frequency
 :) 
 declare function local:create-pair-maps() {
     for $i in collection($query-name) 
     return
        local:write-maps(base-uri($i))
 } ;

  declare function local:write-maps($uri) {
   let $document := doc($uri) 
   let $output-document := concat(substring-before(string($uri), '.xml') , '-MAP.xml')
   let $value-map := map:map()
   let $fill-the-map := for $pair in $document//pair 
                          let $thing-1 := $pair/courtname/string()
                            let $thing-2 := $pair/courtcode/string() 
                            let $value := concat($thing-1, '_', $thing-2)
                            return
                                    if ( $value = map:keys($value-map) )
                                   then map:put($value-map , $value ,
                                        (map:get($value-map , $value) + 1) )
                                   else map:put($value-map , $value , 1)
  let $map-container := <container>{$value-map}</container>

  return
    xdmp:document-insert($output-document , $map-container, (), $map-collection ) 

} ;


(: combine maps :)
declare function local:combine-maps() {
   let $maps := for $i in collection($map-collection) return $i
   let $output-document := concat($query-name, '-combined-map.xml')
   let $value-map-2 := map:map()
   let $fill-the-map := for $_m in $maps
                          let $m := map:map($_m/container/map:map)
                            for $key in map:keys($m)
                              return
                                if ($key = map:keys($value-map-2))
                                                                then map:put($value-map-2 , $key ,
                                                            (map:get($value-map-2 , $key) + map:get($m , $key)))
                                                                   else map:put($value-map-2 , $key , map:get($m , $key))
  let $map-container := <container>{$value-map-2}</container>
  return
    xdmp:document-insert($output-document , $map-container, (), $map-collection)
} ;

(: write results to spreadsheet-friendly XML structure :)
declare function local:maps-to-spreadsheet() {
  let $input-document-name := concat($query-name , '-combined-map.xml')
  return
   <results>{
      for $i in doc($input-document-name)/container/map:map/map:entry
        let $thing-2 := substring-before($i/@key/string(), '_')
        let $thing-1 := substring-after($i/@key/string(), '_')
        order by $thing-2
        return
           <pair frequency="{$i/map:value/string()}">
             <thing-1>{$thing-1}</thing-1>
             <thing-2>{$thing-1}</thing-2>
          </pair>
     }
   </results>
};

local:document-set-creator(1, 1) ,
local:create-pair-maps()  ,
local:combine-maps() ,
local:maps-to-spreadsheet()
```

Comment: I suspect you are facing lock issues, but unless you tell more about your timeouts it is hard to tell. Can you provide more context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of building your own frequency-count documents, consider using [https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:values](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts%3avalues) or [https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:value-co-occurrences](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts%3avalue-co-occurrences) with range indexes. Try the `map` option with either of those functions. That should be much faster and more reliable than building similar functionality yourself.

That said, you might be interested in multi-statement transactions: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions - and I wrote a tutorial that might help: http://blakeley.com/blogofile/2013/06/21/introduction-to-multi-statement-transactions

However using MST may not solve your original problems with memory consumption or timeouts. By inserting these temporary documents you may end up using more memory and more time than you would if you simply pass `map:map` items around between your functions.